# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“TRUE” value must be either True or False.']

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am trying to upload data in the django ORM by a script for which I have written this

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        allocated = row['is_allocated']
        delivery_required_on = row['delivery_required_on']
        linked = row['linked']
        raised_by = row['raised_by']
        raised_for = Company.objects.get(pk=row['raised_for'])    ### double check
        rejected = row['is_rejected']
        reason = row['reason']
        remarks = row['remarks']
        created = row['created_at']
        owner = User.objects.get(pk=row['New owner'])  
        j = literal_eval(row['flows'])
        flows = []
        mobj = MaterialRequest.objects.create(owner=owner, is_allocated=allocated,
                                              delivery_required_on=delivery_required_on, linked=linked,
                                              raised_by=raised_by, raised_for=raised_for, is_rejected=rejected,
                                              reason=reason, remarks=remarks, created=created)
```

It is running fine when the data is something like the following:
[image]

But as soon as `is_allocated` reaches `False` it shows the following error:
[image]

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“TRUE” value must be either
> True or False.']

I am unable to find something related to this

Comment: Share the full error traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like the `is_allocated` property of your model is a boolean. So you should assign a boolean value to it. But your column values in the data frame are strings `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

replacing this line

```py
allocated = row['is_allocated']
```

with

```py
allocated = (row['is_allocated'] == 'TRUE')
```

might help.

if you have `None` other than `True` and `False` values, consider that too.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to store a string in a boolean field. One solution is to change your string type to boolean. Maybe having a function like following in your code solves your problem:

```
def to_boolean(raw_value: str) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(raw_value, str):
        raw_value = str(raw_value)
    raw_value = raw_value.strip()
    return {'true': True, 'false': False}.get(raw_value.lower(), False)
```

and then use it in your loop like (where ever you think your field type is boolean):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    allocated = to_boolean(row['is_allocated'])
    delivery_required_on = row['delivery_required_on']
    linked = row['linked']
    raised_by = row['raised_by']
    raised_for = Company.objects.get(pk=row['raised_for'])    ### double check
    rejected = to_boolean(row['is_rejected'])
    reason = row['reason']
    remarks = row['remarks']
    created = row['created_at']
    owner = User.objects.get(pk=row['New owner'])  
    j = literal_eval(row['flows'])
    flows = []
    mobj = MaterialRequest.objects.create(owner=owner, is_allocated=allocated,
                                          delivery_required_on=delivery_required_on, linked=linked,
                                          raised_by=raised_by, raised_for=raised_for, is_rejected=rejected,
                                          reason=reason, remarks=remarks, created=created)
```